# I can't add Canvas into repeatbox

Tags: smartface.io

I can't add Canvas into a container. How can I add this? When I select container and then click on canvas, it is not working or when I drag canvas into a container it is not working?

Answer (score 1):

It seems a bug of IDE.

There is a workaround for this case. You can cut a Canvas object and paste it into a Container. It will work now.

Or you can create a dynamic canvas object on runtime. As an example;

```
var canvas1 = new SMF.UI.Canvas({
    top: "10%",
    left: "10%",
    width: "80%",
    height: "80%",
    onDraw: function(e) {
        var paint = {
            type : 0, //plain
            strokeColor : "#ff0000",
            fillColor : null,
            width : 5,
        };
        this.drawLine({
            x1 : 10,
            y1 : 10,
            x2 : 50,
            y2 : 50,
            paint : {
                type : 0, //plain
                strokeColor : "#ff0000",
                fillColor : null,
                width : 5,
                }
        });
    }  
});
Pages.Page1.Container1.add(canvas1);
```